# Google Cluod Vision Detect Texts returning nil for NormalizedVertex

Tags: go, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to detect text of an png, image, then I do something like this:

```
image, err := vision.NewImageFromReader(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create image: %v", err)
}

texts, err := client.DetectTexts(ctx, image, nil, 10)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to detect texts: %v", err)
}
```

but when try to look for the normalized vertex, for example

```
texts[0].GetBoundingPoly().GetNormalizedVertices()
```

they are null, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this code snippet:

```
for _, text := range texts {
    // Access the detected text and bounding box vertices
    textContent := text.Description
    vertices := text.BoundingPoly.GetVertices()

    // Process the detected text and bounding box information
    fmt.Printf("Detected Text: %s\n", textContent)
    fmt.Printf("Bounding Box Vertices:\n")
    for _, vertex := range vertices {
        fmt.Printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", vertex.X, vertex.Y)
    }
```

The `GetVertices()` method can retrieve the four bounding box vertices for each detected text. These vertices represent the coordinates of the bounding box that surrounds the detected text.

For text detection, it seems that the API does not provide normalized vertices.

Keep in mind that the bounding box coordinates provided by the Google Cloud Vision API are in pixel units within the image, and they are not normalized. This means that the coordinates are relative to the image's resolution and not scaled to a standardized range. If you require normalized coordinates, you will need to perform additional calculations based on the image dimensions to convert the pixel coordinates to a normalized scale.

Comment: Hi Poala, yes, I am using the BoundingPoly.GetVertices(), but as you said I get them not normalized, and I would like to get them normalized.